# Operand data type varchar is invalid for subtract operator. in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like this :

```
Update T_Assets set F_Asset_CurrentValue=(F_Asset_CurrentValue - '99.58')
Where F_Asset_Code='ITSRDL00001'
```

but I'm getting an error:

> Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Operand data type varchar is invalid for subtract operator

Comment: datatype for "F_Asset_CurrentValue"   column??

Comment: Remove the quotes around `99.58`, it's a numeric literal, not a string literal.

Comment: If datatype for "F_Asset_CurrentValue" is varchar this operation cannot be done.

Comment: needs conversion. use `CONVERT`

Comment: @jarlh it is posible to do  (F_Asset_CurrentValue - '99.58') operation  only if  "F_Asset_CurrentValue" dataype is not equal to varchar

Comment: @yuvi, Really? Probably SQL Server specific behavior. But why do it like that, when you can do it the right way? Write correct SQL, and it's portable and forward compatible.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting this error because **both** sides of of the arithmetic operation are of character type.

In the following example there is an implicit conversion of '123' to 123

```
select      456   - '123';
```

In the following example there is an implicit conversion of '456' to 123

```
select      '456' - 123;
```

The following example yields in a error

```
select      '456' - '123';
```

---

```
Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The data types varchar and varchar are incompatible in the subtract operator.
```

My recommendation is to use explicit conversion

```
cast (F_Asset_CurrentValue as decimal (32,2)) - 99.58
```